# Cross-site access for custom font (Django web project)

Tags: css, fonts, font-face, webfonts

Via implementing `@font-face`, I added a custom font to a web project for a client. However, the custom font never loads, giving the error:

```
downloadable font: download failed (font-family: "droid_arabic_naskh" style:normal weight:normal stretch:normal src index:1): bad URI or cross-site access not allowed source: http://mysite.azureedge.net/css/fonts/droidnaskh-regular-webfont.woff2/woff/ttf
```

Is there any way to fix this? Or should I revert the custom font?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off that URL is not even valid. Not sure if you changed that just for posting purposes.

You should download and import the font locally.

This should be the css format:

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: myFirstFont;
    src: url(sansation_bold.woff);
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Ref: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_fonts.asp

Comment: Yes, changed the url for posting purposes, so don't worry about URL validity.

Comment: @HassanBaig well your issue is URL based as the error claims. Post your CSS import here .

Comment: Actually `font-face` et al is correct, the culprit is I placed the fonts in the static folder - that folder is mapped onto a CDN in the live environment. It works fine locally, not in production. It seems from your answer that I need to put it in the local server, not CDN.